# Selenium - Get element after a specific element (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

[image]

As you can see from the picture, the pagination is a bit different. So my idea is to get the position of the current-page and get the link for the `a` tag.

```
        current_page= driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.current-page")
        driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"a").click()
```

but I didn't know to use the current_page element to find the `a` tag after it and click on it.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the `next element` using `current page` reference you can use the following css selector in one liner or XPATH option.

```
next_page= driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.current-page+a")
print(next_page.get_attribute("href"))
next_page.click()
```

---

Or you can use this.

```
current_page= driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.current-page")
current_page.find_element(By.XPATH,"./following::a[1]").click()
```